# How to get Chrome context menu not grouping profiles?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, profile, chrome-profile

How ungroup the "Open as..." context menu entry?
If I am using only 2 Profiles, I'm good

[Screen of only 2 profiles](https://i.postimg.cc/52kwCT71/Chrome-canary-open-link-as-person-1-right-click-option-300x211.png)

As you can see in the screenshot, I have to do two clicks for opening an url link within the other profile.

[Screen of 3 or more profiles](https://i.postimg.cc/X7G1qK7r/Bildschirmfoto-von-2019-06-02-18-48-50.png)

But if I have a third profile, the context menu changes, it creates an expandable item, grouping the other profiles. That is very annoying, because I have to navigate first to the "Open as" line and then after a short delay or an additional click the profile-list appeares where I need to select appropriate profile.

Can we revert the behaviour to list all available profiles within the root context menu?

May we create a keyboard-shortcut for every profile, so pressing the asssigned button while clicking on any links, will open the url in that profile.

Or is there an extension for doing the job? I couldn find any useful information to solve this...

Thanks in advance for any helpful advices :) 
(sorry for the spellingmistakes)

Offtopic:
(migrating from ff to chromium. Everyday web-based apps for end-consumers getting more focus, which means in my eyes, programmatically design gets more limited due to the main concept behind our standardized world wide web. And additionally user control gets worse everyday because that's the new key to generate money no longer just for complex & highly specialized products. e.g. timeinvestigation is enormous to through out all the bugs and bullshit extensions to get a reasonably useful tool for accessing the world wide web.)

Comment: Neither Chrome nor extensions can customize the built-in UI or menus.

Comment: I usually avoid building software by myself, csn you say if even with customizations on the original hopefully open source code it wont be possible?? I just got another chrome issu

Comment: You can investigate the source code at https://cs.chromium.org